# Nesting sass/scss using class attribute starts with

Tags: sass

I have the following scss/sass:

```
.c-slider {
  $parent: &;
  [class^=c-slider-thumb]{
  #{$parent}__item {
    margin-left:0;
  }
}
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
expected "]".
  stdin 3:9  root stylesheet on line 3 at column 9
```

I want to achieve:

```
 [class^=c-slider-thumb]{ 
  .c-slider__item{
    margin-left:0;
  }
}
```

How can be done ?

Comment: Have you tried to escape the ^ character with backslash? I am a noob in sass, but intuitively this springs into my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you can achieve it

```
.c-slider {
  $parent: &;
  @at-root [class^=c-slider-thumb]{
  #{$parent}__item {
    margin-left:0;
    }
  }
}
```

Your result will be

```
[class^=c-slider-thumb] .c-slider__item {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```